# Flutter run stuck on white screen on ios device

Tags: ios, flutter, mercadopagosdk

Add to the project the native library [MercadoPagoSDK](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios) to the pod file in ios and everything normal, however the project stopped working out of nowhere after a couple of weeks. The only message that appears in xcode is **thread 1 exc_bad_access** in front of the registry of a plugin called **facebook_audience_network**  and the app stuck on white screen on my iphone device.

My flutter version:

```
Flutter 1.22.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9b2d32b605 (hace 6 semanas) • 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
Engine • revision 2f0af37152
Tools • Dart 2.10.5
```

And my log:
[Flutter run --verbose](https://gist.github.com/redemtiom/09676365cd131e09a713b12434045240)

Comment: But did you confirm that it was that lib? When starting the application, no stacktrace bursts?

Comment: the only thing I could see in the logs was the following: /Users/redemtiom/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/facebook_audience_network-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FacebookAudienceNetworkNativeAd.swift
                     :596:38: warning: cast from 'Error' to unrelated type 'String' always fails
                             let errorStr: String = error as? String ?? "";, but I couldn't confirm properly.